# Pandas - Check if all values from a list are in the headers of dataframe, if not add column and value 'null'

Tags: pandas

I have the below code that creates a dataframe that is coming from an API. I have a list with the headers (`headers_list`) and I want to check if each element is in the dataframe, if not add column to dataframe and add 'null'. Also its important its in the correct order from the list.

( I've hardcoded `data` as an example of a response missing 'biography' since its missing I want to add in and have the value 'null'.)

```
headers_list = ['followers_count', 'biography', 'media_count', 'profile_picture_url', 'username', 'website', 'id']
```

Below is an example of my code:

```
    data = {'followers_count': 8192, 'follows_count': 427, 'media_count': 317, 'profile_picture_url': 'https://90860011962368_a.jpg', 'username': 'yes', 'website': 'http://GOL.COM/', 'id': '17843651'}
    x = pd.DataFrame(user_fields_data.items())
    x.set_index(0, inplace=True)
    user_fields_df = x.transpose()
```

I know I can do this but then I would have to make several 'if' statements, wondering if there is a better way?

```
    if 'biography' not in user_fields_df:
        user_fields_df.insert(1, "biography", 'null')
```

Also, I tried this but it add the column to the end, and I need to to add to the correct location:

```
for col in headers_list:
    if col not in user_fields_df.columns:
        user_fields_df[col] = 'null'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `reindex` columns (axis = 1) with the `headers_list`:

```
user_fields_df.reindex(headers_list, axis=1)

#0 followers_count  biography media_count  ... username          website        id
#1            8192        NaN         317  ...      yes  http://GOL.COM/  17843651
```

Comment: that's amazing! I'm still not sure why this works I have to read up on 'reindex'. It even worked when I removed other columns not just 1. Thanks!!

Comment: It *Conform Series/DataFrame to new index with optional filling logic*. You can read more about the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)